# how put string in a list with struct ? (C language)

Tags: c, string, list

main.c:

```
#include "lista.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    LISTA p1;
    iniciaLista(&p1);
    inserir(&p1, "Fabio");
    return 0;
}
```

lista.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX 60

typedef struct{
   char nome[50];
}REGISTRO;

typedef struct{
    REGISTRO A[MAX +1];
    int qtdElemen;
}LISTA;

void iniciaLista(LISTA* l);
void inserir(LISTA* l, char ch);
```

lista.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lista.h"

void iniciaLista(LISTA* l){
    l->qtdElemen = 0;
}
void inserir(LISTA* l, char ch){
    int i = l->qtdElemen;
    if(l->qtdElemen == MAX) return;
    else{
        strcpy(&ch, (l->A[i].nome);
        l->qtdElemen++;
    }
    return;

}
```

i'm trying put a name in a list but i cant and dont know why, What can I be doing wrong?, I get several errors when I try to run:

**lista.c:26:32: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]**

**In file included from lista.c:3:
/usr/include/string.h:125:70: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘char’**

Comment: The second argument to `strcpy` is supposed to the the address of memory where it will read the string from.  But instead of a memory address, you gave it a `char`.

Comment: Your function `inserir` shall take `const char* c` instead a `char`.

Comment: try to use `void inserir(LISTA* l, const char* ch)`

Answer (score 0):

```
void inserir(LISTA* l, const char ch);
```

ch is a single character and not a string (char[] / char*)

you also should make sure that ch is really null terminated and with less than 50 characters ortherwise if it's the user that inputs data he can perform a bufferoverflow attack. i'd rather use strncpy/strlcpy here

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct problems:

- in `main` is should be `inserir(&p1, "Fabio");` instead of `void inserir(&p1, "Fabio");`
- in the declaration and the implementation of `inserir` it should be `void inserir(LISTA* l, const char *ch)` (emphasis on *`const char *ch`*).